# Facing issue to handle thread properly

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter

I am working a project where i need 3 thread and out of them two should work concurrently and last one should start after some delay (i.e like after 10 secs of start of other two).My code structure is look like what i written  below

```
def Rpm():
  ..........
def Tor():
 .......
def read1():
.......
def read2():
.......
def get():
read1()
time.sleep(0.1)
read2()
time.sleep(0.1)
root.after(200,get)
def enter():
 ......
t1=threading.Thread(target=Rpm)
t2=threading.Thread(target=Tor)
t3=threading.Timer(10.0,get)
t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
root=Tk.tk()
......
root.mainloop()
```

My full code is look like somewhat like this.
and i am facing issue with 3rd thread which isn't behaving proper.
where is the issue after a lot trial and error i am not able to find.Please guide me guys.
My code flow is like for 1st 10 secs 1st two thread should work concurrently and after 10 secs 3 rd thread should join and update itself in every 200 ms.And finally after 1 min 3 thread should stop and wait to "command" for restart.

Comment: What do you mean *"isn't behaving proper"*?

Comment: @acw1668,means its not updated after 200 ms,it is executes once only

Comment: As I don't have your full code, I created some [`code`](https://pastebin.com/cCN2CWQU) similar to yours and it works.

Comment: @acw1668,Thanks a lot it is now working.The only difference is you used `daemon=True` which i didn't use in my code.What is exact use of `daemon`?

Comment: A daemon thread will be terminated when the main thread is terminated.